# ¿Como hacer que componentDidMount se vuelva a ejecutar sin tener que refrescar la pagina?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Estoy haciendo una aplicación de lista de tareas en React, y ahora mismo la app carga las tareas (`tasks`) desde una Api Rest cuando se carga la página:

```js
this.state{
  tasks: []
}
// Rellenando el array de tasks:
componentDidMount(){

  axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/api/tasks/${id}`)
              .then((response) => {
                  let tasks = response.data;
                  this.setState({
                      tasks: tasks
                  })
              }).catch((error) => console.log(error))
              
}
```

Resulta que en la misma página se puede añadir localmente tareas mediante un `input` Cuando se añaden, hago una petición POST para añadir la tarea:

```js
createTask = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        console.log('añadiendo task en bbdd...')
        
        // Post new task in Api
        const nombreTask = event.target.elements.nombretask.value;
        axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/task', {
            name: nombreTask,
            list: this.state.id_lista
        }).then((res) => {
            console.log(res)
        }).catch(error => console.error(error))
}
```

```html
<form>
<input />
<button type="submit" onClick={this.createTask}>Añadir Tarea</button>
</form>
```

Después de esto lo que necesito es que el array de `tasks` en `this.state` esté actualizado, entonces simplemente añado otra vez la peticion GET de las tareas, dentro del método `createTask`

```js
createTask = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        console.log('añadiendo task en bbdd..')
        
        // Añadir tarea en bbdd...
        const nombreTask = event.target.elements.nombretask.value;
        axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/task', {
            name: nombreTask,
            list: this.state.id_lista
        }).then((res) => {
            console.log(res)
        }).catch(error => console.error(error))

        // Get otra vez las tareas, y actualiza el estado
        let id = this.props.match.params.id_lista
        axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/api/tasks/${id}`)
            .then((response) => {
                let tasks = response.data;
                this.setState({
                    tasks: tasks
                })
            }).catch((error) => console.log(error))
        //clear value of input:
        document.getElementById("create-list-form").reset();
    }
```

El problema es que el HTML que se encarga de mostrar las tareas NO MUESTRA el estado actualizado:

```js
<div className="the-list-popUp">
                        {this.state.tasks.map((item, i) =>
                            <ul>
                                <li className="item-lista" key={i}>{item.name}</li>
                                <div className="double-button-wrapper">
                                    <button onClick={this.getTaskAsDone.bind(this, item)} className="btn btn-success">Hecho</button>
                                    <button onClick={this.deleteTask.bind(this, item)} className="btn btn-secondary">Borrar</button>
                                </div>
                            </ul>
                        )}
                    </div>
```

Creía que en React cuando habia cambios en el DOM se actualizaba automáticamente sin refrescar toda la página. ¿Que es lo que necesito hacer para que el `<div>` de arriba vuelva a "buscar" las `tasks` en `this.state` y así que muestre la última que acaba de añadir el usuario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución un poco mas limpia es usando [*Async/Await*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/funcion_asincrona), lo cual te permite que sea mas legible y sin la necesidad de un `setTimeout` lo cual no es nada recomendable.

```
createTask = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('añadiendo task en bbdd..');

        // Añadir tarea en bbdd...
        const nombreTask = event.target.elements.nombretask.value;
        const responsePost = await axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/task', {
            name: nombreTask,
            list: this.state.id_lista,
        }).catch(error => console.error(error));

        console.log(responsePost);
        // Get otra vez las tareas, y actualiza el estado
        let id = this.props.match.params.id_lista;
        const responseGet = await axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/api/tasks/${id}`)
                                       .catch(error => console.error(error));
        if(responseGet.data){ 
          // O alguna otra validacion para prevenir errores o arrays vacios
          this.setState({tasks: responseGet.data});  
        }

        //clear value of input:
        document.getElementById('create-list-form').reset();
};
```

También puedes hacerlo anidando promesas, cologando el `get()` dentro del `.then()`, siempre y cuando hagas un buen uso de [arrows functions.](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/Arrow_functions)

---

### Async/Await:

Una función *async* puede contener una expresión *await*, la cual pausa la ejecución de la función asíncrona y espera la resolución de la *Promise* pasada y, a continuación, reanuda la ejecución de la función *async* y devuelve el valor resuelto.

En palabras mas simples, hace que tu ejecución sea secuencial, espera a que se resuelva la función puesta en el *await* (El *POST* o el *GET*, en este caso que son API calls y tienen demora de respuesta), cuando se resuelve pasa al siguiente paso.

---

> PD: Si tienes acceso a la API lo ideal (en este caso) seria que el
>   POST, retorne la nueva lista actualizada, cuando sea exitoso el proceso.

Comment: Al final lo he hecho anidando promesas como has dicho también, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

El problema que estás teniendo es que *crees* que el `axios.get` se va a ejecutar después de que termine la petición `axios.post`, sin embargo JS no funciona así.
Tu código lo que hará será lanzar la petición `post` e inmediatamente después hará el `get`.

Las [*promesas*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Usar_promesas) sirven para esperar una operación asíncrona, y lo que quieras que suceda cuando termine la operación lo especificas en el método `then` de la promesa, y un eventual error lo capturas con el método `catch`.

En tu caso, lo apropiado sería esto:

```
createTask = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log('añadiendo task en bbdd..')

    // Añadir tarea en bbdd...
    const nombreTask = event.target.elements.nombretask.value;
    axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/task', {
        name: nombreTask,
        list: this.state.id_lista
    }).then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
        // Una vez que axios finalizó la petición, ahora sí actualizamos
        let id = this.props.match.params.id_lista
        axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/api/tasks/${id}`)
            .then((response) => {
                let tasks = response.data;
                this.setState({
                    tasks: tasks
                });
            }).catch((error) => console.log(error))
        //clear value of input:
        document.getElementById("create-list-form").reset();
    }).catch(error => console.error(error));
}
```

Como puedes ver, la operación de actualización la dejé dentro del `then` del `axios.post` que haces al principio.

Siempre ten en cuenta que cuando ejecutes una operación asíncrona, el resto del código se seguirá ejecutando sin importar cuánto tiempo demore *esa* operación, **a menos que** uses una [función asíncrona (async/await)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/funcion_asincrona).

Answer (score 0):

Fue un error bastante bobo, evidentemente el GET no sacaba las tasks actualizadas porque no le daba tiempo, lo he solucionado añadiendo un simple setTimeOut, **aunque si alguien tiene un enfoque más optimizado, lo agradecería**:

```js
let id = this.props.match.params.id_lista
        setTimeout(() => {
            axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/api/tasks/${id}`)
                .then((response) => {
                    let tasks = response.data;
                    this.setState({
                        tasks: tasks
                    })
                }).catch((error) => console.log(error))

            console.log(this.state.tasks)
        }, 3000)
```